# How to inject a custom view to a viewGroup declared in an xml at runtime?

Tags: android, layout, custom-view

I' ve designed a xml layout-file with some standard ui-components in it. So far it works fine.
In my Java-code I've implemented a custom view which extends a SurfaceView for the purpose of animating things. Now I want to inject this custom view at runtime to the ui defined in the layout-file.
Do I have to provide for an empty view filler for that custom view in the XML?
How does this work? Can you show me a simple code snippet please ? Thanks

Comment: This view you have created, you want to keep it as a seperate xml file?

Comment: I have one view for the basic layout, it's in a separate xml file. The other view is hard coded and not referenced by any xml files, yet. Is it possible to reference it in my first xml-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ViewGroup addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) method. 
Also you can use [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>
```

where, this linearLayout is in basic layout while this layout in `include` is another layout file. So you can even reuse this layout multiple times.

[Check examples here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

this way it works, but is there any more elegant way to do this, e.g. with a ViewStub ?

```
    // the animation-view:
    final LighthouseView lighthouseView = new LighthouseView(this, controller);
    controller.registerView(lighthouseView);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lighthouse);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lighthouse_container);
    container.addView(lighthouseView, 0);
    setContentView(container);
```